# how to create rabbitmq using jms template

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I created Rabbitmq with `x-message-ttl,x-dead-letter-exchange,x-dead-letter-routing-key`. The queue name is `tempQueue`.

I integrated Rabitmq with JMSTemplate, when I sent the message to above-created queue got the error like.

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'tempQueue' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '10000' of type 'long', class-id=50, method-id=10).
```

My code is :

```
public void sample(){
    jmsTemplate.send("tempQueue", new MessageCreator() {
                    @Override
                    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws                JMSException {
                        BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
                        try {

                            message.writeBytes("Welcome".getBytes());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return message;
                    }

                });  

}
```

if I sent normally created queue, without any additional properties like x-message-ttl ,its working fine.

for RabbitTemplate both cases are working fine, but integrate with JMSTemplate extra arguements are not working..